# Python - Count character in a text file between a specific character

Tags: python-3.x, count, character

Given text file containing

```
1 MS1
2 MS2
3 MS2
4 MS1
5 MS2
6 MS2
7 MS2
```

I would like to count the amount of MS2 between two MS1 and return the result with he RT value of MS . Meaning like:

```
1 2
4 3
```

To determine rows of the MS1 and MS2 I was able to do with something like

```
df.Level.str.contains(""))
```

Would you then try to loop over each line and then simply subtract the rows where to find a MS1 and write a new file for example? OR is there an easier way to get this (and faster?)

UPDATE : I deleted RT / LEVEL , MS_Count as being column headers
Thx

Comment: Can you confirm what are "RT" and "Level". Is this like a space separated file, with the values separated by a space? I din't get your question either.

Comment: that would be the column header , it is from a tab limited file, I just would like to get rid of the MS2 rows, however counting them  e.g. how many rows with MS2 are in the file after each MS1 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if something like this solves it:

```
A = your_input
for i in A.split('MS1'):
    i.count('MS2')
```